# .svc handler for IIS Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012, master-data-services

While configuring the `SQL Server 2012 Master Data Services`, I am having following problem

The required `.svc handler` mappings are not installed in `IIS`.

What I want to do is that, I want to query my database using a URL so that I can retrieve data directly using the URL it self just like we can store the querystring parameters into SQL Server

How do I deal with it, I followed several documents but not any ideas.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come across these types of errors a few times when installing MDS, the problem usually comes about because just having IIS installed is not enough, there are loads of other role services and features that you need to enable and install as well which the setup program doesn't tell you about.

Thankfully they are all documented here:

[Web Application Requirements (Master Data Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633744%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

And, if you've missed any, you can go back, install them and then re-launch the configuration tool to complete the setup without having to re-install MDS from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

To fix this issue, open a **command prompt** and go to the **.NET directory**

(for example %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319).

Run the command: **aspnet_regiis –i**

For further details check:[SVC Handler mapping error in MDS Configuration Manager](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2390.troubleshoot-installation-and-configuration-issues-master-data-services-in-sql-server.aspx#SVCHandlerMappingError)